# android Platform Versions

Tags: android, version

Does anybody knows when there will be more updated information than the following info provided by google a couple of month ago?

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

maybe another source for more up to date information?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.radarnow.net/statistics.htm

Comment: I have a few popular apps and my breakdown on Flurry is similar.
40% 2.0.1
39% 1.5
18.8% 1.6
2% 2.1
1% other

I have asked on google groups for them to update that but still no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an update on the page:
https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

So I guess they will do some updates over time.